# How can I show same video as a background in all View Controllers without any interruption during the pages transition?

Tags: swift

There are 2 pages(`ViewController`) in Main.storyboard: `HomeViewController` and `DetailViewController`

I gave a storyboard ID for the `DetailViewController`:`DetailPage`

I have added a button into first page to take user to the second page.

I also have added a back button into second page to take user to the first page back.

I need to show a video in the background in all pages.

So I have added an UIView component in all pages to show a video.

I gave 0,0,0,0 constraint values for these 2 UIView components in each pages.

First let me share source codes and then I would like to ask my questions.

`HomeViewController.swift` file

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

private var player: AVPlayer!

@IBOutlet weak var outlet4TheVideoUiView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureVideoIssue()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    configureVideoIssue()
}

func configureVideoIssue()
{
    // BACKGROUND VIDEO SCOPE STARTS
    let path  = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clouds", ofType: "mp4")!)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
    self.player = player
    let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    newLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    outlet4TheVideoUiView.frame = self.view.bounds
    outlet4TheVideoUiView.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)

    newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    player.play()

    // video bitince tekrar oynatmak için
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.videoDidPlayToEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: player.currentItem)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    // BACKGROUND VIDEO SCOPE ENDS
}

@objc func enteredBackground() {
    player.pause()
}

@objc func enteredForeground() {
    player.play()
}

@objc func videoDidPlayToEnd(notification: Notification)
{
    let player: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    player.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
}

@IBAction func linkBtnClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailPage") as! DetailViewController
    controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    //present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    show(controller, sender: nil)
}
}
```

`DetailViewController.swift` file

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

private var player: AVPlayer!

@IBOutlet weak var outlet4TheVideoUiView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureVideoIssue()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func configureVideoIssue()
{
    // BACKGROUND VIDEO SCOPE STARTS
    let path  = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "clouds", ofType: "mp4")!)
    let player = AVPlayer(url: path)
    self.player = player
    let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    newLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    outlet4TheVideoUiView.frame = self.view.bounds
    outlet4TheVideoUiView.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)

    newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    player.play()

    // video bitince tekrar oynatmak için
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.videoDidPlayToEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: player.currentItem)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(enteredForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    // BACKGROUND VIDEO SCOPE ENDS
}

@objc func enteredBackground() {
    player.pause()
}

@objc func enteredForeground() {
    player.play()
}

@objc func videoDidPlayToEnd(notification: Notification)
{
    let player: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    player.seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)
}

@IBAction func btnBackClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

**First Question:** I am sure that it shouldn't be like this because same codes are written in both ViewControllers. So how can I avoid this? Any suggestions? I should use same video ui view object as a background for all view controllers. Does it make sense? If it does not make sense. What should I do? For example, I use `asp.net` `user control` component in `Visual Studio` for this scenario. I create one video component(user control) and I can use this component for all pages as a background.

**Second Question:** (if we can't find a solution to the first question)Let's assume that app user sees Homepage right now. And let's assume that user clicks button to see secondpage(detail page)after 10th second. Button click action takes user to the second page but video starts from the first second. Video should continue from 10th second or 11th second. How can I do this?

**Third Question:** Second page comes from the bottom after i click button in first page. Can second page comes with fading first page out animation and appearing second page animation?

**Important details:** Video should stop after app is minimized and should continue after app is maximized by app user. And other important detail is: buttons are not inside of the video view. User can see buttons above the video with this way. Let me show layers for the components in order with an image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can do this is set your view on the `rootWindow` and then set all your views' background color to clear.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let window=self.window!
    backgroundVideoView.bounds = window.bounds
    window.addSubview(backgroundVideoView)
    playVideo()

    return true
}
```

Here, `backgroundVideoView` refers to the view which will be playing your video.

Although, I must warn you, this will consume a lot of memory but will get you the desired behavior.

Comment: I was trying to solve it myself until post gets a reply. I did this: I created a Base UIViewController file. And then i have added all these video stuff in this file. And then DetailViewController and HomeViewController ..etc are got inheritance by BaseViewController. Will this consume a lot of memory also? @nothingwhatsover

Comment: But above solution(Adding a BaseViewController & inheritance issue) solves only first question. How can I solve second and third problem during the pages transition?

Comment: Dear @nothingwhatsoever Can you expand your solution please? I need clear details for the backgroundVideoView. Thanks.

Comment: if added on the root window, you won't have the occurance of the scenario for second and third question. do try it once.